# React Router , protect static images

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have created a website using react. Images of the webpages are accessable using url like - 
http://localhost:3000/1.jpg

I want to protect and not display that images inside public folder,
I have tried below code, It does not work if i give image name dot extension in url , it works if that name image is not present in public folder

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import App from "../App";
import PageNotFound from "../components/PageNotFound/PageNotFound";

class Router extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={App} />
          <Route path="*" component={PageNotFound} />
        </Switch>
      </BrowserRouter>
    );
  }
}

export default Router;
```

Comment: Can you elaborate? Do you not want users to see the images in your `public` directory? How should they see the images instead? And if they shouldn't see them at all, why are they in your `public` directory

Comment: I dont want users to see images in public directory, Images are accessable via url , which i want to avoid.

Comment: Maybe I'm not following, but how are the user's browser supposed to download the images, if you don't want them accessible?

Comment: Yes you are right, i thought there would be some way to not allow user to see that image using url.

Comment: You can use `.htaccess` to prevent direct access of images from the public folder

Comment: yes, i will try that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suggestion would be to put the images in a folder  `public/images`(usually by convention)
and then do something like this

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import App from "../App";
import PageNotFound from "../components/PageNotFound/PageNotFound";

class Router extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={App} />
          <Route path="*" component={PageNotFound} />
          <Route path="/images/public/*" component={PageNotFound} />
        </Switch>
      </BrowserRouter>
    );
  }
}

export default Router;
```